# Function not working

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I am trying to use the html code with angular elements on home page of a php forum script. I am adding this php code into index.template.php ( as supposed to be ). But it does not display anything.

```
<?php

/**
  * Will help you change font and colour on your forum without change templates or making CSS edits.

 */

function template_colour_picker()

{
global $txt;

echo'
<html>'

  <div id="colourpicker" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ngPicky">    

      <label>$txt['font']</label>  
          <input type="text" ng-model="fontName" placeholder="$txt['Enter font name here']">
       <label>$txt['color']</label> 
          <input type="text" ng-model="fontColour" placeholder="$txt['Enter colour name here']">
       <label>$txt['background']</label> 
          <input type="text" ng-model="bgColour" placeholder="$txt'[Enter backgroundcolour name here']">
          <hr>
          <div class="{{fontName}} {{fontColour}} {{bgColour}}">$txt['Text']</div>
</div>
'</html>';

}

?>
```

> **Parse error:** syntax error, unexpected 'ng' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in .../themes/Silk_af_v155/index.template.php on line 405

Comment: What exactly is not working (I don't even see you calling the function in this code)

Comment: What kind of error? Can you show us the message you get?

Comment: what is your error message..?

Comment: May be my PHP is faulty. Do you guys find any error in the code ?

Comment: Sorry guys. It was the angular elements causing the issue. It says 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'ng' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in .../themes/Silk_af_v155/index.template.php on line 405    Any fix possible that you guys know ?

Comment: Nobody can or will help you unless you show the error, as otherwise it's just a guessing game.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, was editing to add the error.

Answer (score 1):

You have all kinds of [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) errors. Pay careful attention to where you have your single quotes (`'`) and periods (`.`). Check yours against this:

```
<?php
function template_colour_picker()
    {
        global $txt;
        echo '
        <html>
        <div id="colourpicker" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ngPicky">    
            <label>'.$txt['font'].'</label>  
            <input type="text" ng-model="fontName" placeholder="'.$txt['Enter font name here'].'">
            <label>'.$txt['color'].'</label> 
            <input type="text" ng-model="fontColour" placeholder="'.$txt['Enter colour name here'].'">
            <label>'.$txt['background'].'</label> 
            <input type="text" ng-model="bgColour" placeholder="'.$txt['Enter backgroundcolour name here'].'">
            <hr>
            <div class="{{fontName}} {{fontColour}} {{bgColour}}">'.$txt['Text'].'</div>
        </div>
        </html>';
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks @Rasclatt . The error has vanished. But the page is not displaying anything from the html. Does php allow use of <html ng-app> as it should be ?

Comment: If you view source, is there HTML there?

Comment: Also, are these really keys from an array: `'Enter colour name here'`, `'Enter font name here'`, etc?

Comment: Sadly, no. There is nothing called ngPicky in the source.

Comment: I think you need to add more to  your code above on how you are using this function.

Comment: To be frank, I just want to use html code in the home page. I was suggested to use a function in index.template.php

Comment: Does your page require dynamic input from the `$txt` array? Is there such an array even?

Comment: I apologize. I should have told you my php knowledge is very poor. Since I was told to use a function, I tried to imitate a function in another template which had a .txt

Comment: Can you post all your script that you have so far for your page in an edit? It would be helpful to see what you are trying to do, because it sounds like you are not sure yourself what you are trying to do.

Comment: I simply want to display output of  <html ng-app>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ngPicky">    

      <label>font</label>  
          <input type="text" ng-model="fontName" placeholder="Enter font name here">
       <label>color</label> 
          <input type="text" ng-model="fontColour" placeholder="Enter colour name here">
       <label>background</label> 
          <input type="text" ng-model="bgColour" placeholder="Enter backgroundcolour name here">
          <hr>
          <div class="{{fontName}} {{fontColour}} {{bgColour}}">Text</div>
</div>
</html>  on home page.

Comment: Contents of home page is decided by a template called index.template.php

Comment: I have angularjs and ngPicky plugin added to the software. Both are getting loaded as well.

Comment: Ok, well unfortunately that is where my expertise stops. But, if you want to write html on the page, just write what you have. You don't need a function. A function is useful if you are trying to do dynamic things to your page.

Comment: Thanks. Simply add HTML on php file ? No need for echo and all ?

Comment: Yes, simply write the HTML like you normally would on a page with a `.htm` extension. PHP will run it as normal HTML.

Comment: When I add on bottom of php file, it does run. But the page loads very slow and html is displayed on top.

Comment: Do you mind joining me at adminforum.in for sometime. I would like to share some screen shots with you and the comment system here is very limited.

Comment: It's on local host. :(

Comment: Sure show me whatever

Comment: Thank you. My user name is wizard there. I will start a thread in a moment.